# The fastest way to swap the two lowest bits in an unsigned int in C++

Tags: c++, binary, bitwise-operators

Assume that I have:

```
unsigned int x = 883621;
```

which in binary is :

```
00000000000011010111101110100101
```

I need the fastest way to swap the two lowest bits:

```
00000000000011010111101110100110
```

Note: To clarify: If x is 7 (0b111), the output should be still 7.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Doesn't that flip the bits instead of reversing their order?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Well, I am not sure about my understanding either, OP should add more examples.

Comment: I edited the question. By reverse, I meant swap. Thanks

Comment: To clarify: If `x` is 7 (`0b111`), the the output should be still 7 or 4 (`0b100`)?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen it should be still 7. Only swap it, please.

Comment: The fastest way is almost certainly dependent on the CPU. I mean not just x86 vs ARM, but even between different Intel models. And of course, this only really matters if you have a million of them, in which case AVX solutions become sensible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swap two bits in given integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501432/swap-two-bits-in-given-integer)

Comment: @A.Smoliak, not really since this one is about the two lowest bits. The multiplication by three trick could be used here to transform xy to xyxy and noting the middle of the latter contains the exchange.

Comment: A. Smoliak Thanks. However, the answers for general questions (bit m and n) might be slower than when you know that always m=0 and n=1. BTW, the answers there were also useful. Thanks.

Comment: @Bathsheba: My other answer would work - it calculates `A^B`  and multiplies that by ` `1<<M+1<<N`; in this case `M=1, N=0, 1<<M+1<<N = 3`

Comment: @MSalters: Indeed - I've upvoted both your answers. On your convolution point, note https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem

Comment: Do you have an array of such numbers ro swap? If so, vectorized table lookup can beat usual table lookup

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have few bytes of memory to spare, I would start with a lookup table:

```cpp
constexpr unsigned int table[]={0b00,0b10,0b01,0b11};

unsigned int func(unsigned int x){
    auto y = (x & (~0b11)) |( table[x&0b11]);
    return y;  
}
```

[Quickbench `-O3` of all the answers so far](https://quick-bench.com/q/PgnZjVFTpaEUZGgBlkEUzm5rtZk).

[Quickbench `-Ofast` of all the answers so far](https://quick-bench.com/q/zcq0pUWnXgmqgDeT3I-P-fSr2wU).

(Plus my `ifelse` naive idea.)

[Feel free to add yourself and edit my answer].

Please do correct me if you believe the benchmark is incorrect, I am not an expert in reading assembly. So hopefully `volatile x` prevented caching the result between loops.

Comment: if table is { 0b00, 0b11, 0b11, 0b00 }, y = table[x & 0b11] ^ x.  :)

Comment: @dyungwang Interesting, thanks. I'll add it to the benchmark.

Comment: @dyungwang Seems to be the fastest so far.

Comment: So interesting idea! I am not sure if it is the fastest.

Comment: @MojtabaValizadeh That's why added the benchmark. Of course you should profile your own code and see what works in your environment.

Answer (score 7):

I'll ignore the top bits for a second - there's a trick using multiplication. Multiplication is really a convolution operation, and you can use that to shuffle bits.

In particular, assume the two lower bits are AB. Multiply that by 0b0101, and you get ABAB. You'll see that the swapped bits BA are the middle bits.

Hence,
x = `(x & ~3U) | ((((x&3)*5)>>1)&3)`

[edit] The &3 is needed to strip the top A bit, but with std::uint_32_t you can use overflow to lose that bit for free - multiplication then gets you the result BAB0'0000'0000'0000'0000'0000'0000'0000'0000' :

```
x = (x & ~3U) | ((((x&3)*0xA0000000)>>30));
```

Comment: Interesting idea. However, I think multiplication is expensive.

Comment: @MojtabaValizadeh: You'd be surprised. `*5` on x86 is `lea eax, [eax*4 + eax] `. It uses optimized hardware generally used for address generation.

Comment: Your versions gave wrong results for `x=7`: https://godbolt.org/z/P9a857e4P `foo1` and `foo4` functions

Comment: @mch: O, right. I was to quick combining two lines, you need to do &3 first (strip AB bits). if you have ABC*5 you get `AB(c+A)BC` where C+A can trigger repeated carries. Messy.,

Answer (score 5):

I would use

```
x = (x & ~0b11) | ((x & 0b10) >> 1) | ((x & 0b01) << 1);
```

Comment: It looks great. I am not sure if we have anything faster.

Comment: From Quimby's benchmark, it seems it is the slower ;-) but IMO the most readable (with table variant).

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by the table idea, but with the table as a simple constant instead of an array. We just need mask(00)==00, mask(01)==11, mask(10)=11, masK(11)==11.

```
constexpr unsigned int table = 0b00111100;

unsigned int func(unsigned int x) {
    auto xormask = (table >> ((x&3) * 2)) &3;
    x ^= xormask;
    return x;  
}
```

This also uses the xor-trick from dyungwang to avoid isolating the top bits.

Comment: Note that the constant is a 6 bit constant; ARM and x86 can encode this as an immediate value in the instruction stream.  This takes no extra data memory, it should all fit in a single cache line.

Answer (score 4):

Another idea, to avoid stripping the top bits. Assume x has the bits XXXXAB, then we want to x-or it with 0000(A^B)(A^B). Thus

```
auto t = x^(x>>1); // Last bit is now A^B
t &=1; // take just that bit
t *= 3; // Put in the last two positions
x ^= t; // Change A to B and B to A.
```

Answer (score 2):

Just looking from a mathematical point of view, I would start with a `rotate_left()` function, which rotates a list of bits one place to the left (`011` becomes `110`, then `101`, and then back `011`), and use this as follows:

```
int func(int input){
  return rotate_left(rotate_left((input / 4))) + rotate_left(input % 4);
}
```

Using this on the author's example `11010111101110100101`:

```
input = 11010111101110100101;
input / 4 = 110101111011101001;
rotate_left(input / 4) = 1101011110111010010;
rotate_left(rotate_left(input / 4) = 11010111101110100100;

input % 4 = 01;
rotate_left(input % 4) = 10;

return 11010111101110100110;
```

There is also a `shift()` function, which can be used (twice!) for replacing the integer division.